# Displaying list as collapsed

Tags: html, css

I have created a list and want to display it as collapsed and after clicking on a list item it should be expanded. I have created demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UDKLK/2/).
I am using following javascript method:

```
function toggle(id){
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if (e.style.display == '') {
        e.style.display = 'none'; 
    } else {
        e.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

I have the following issues:

1. With this code Expand/Collapse is not happening in jsFiddle where as same code is working properly in html.
2. By default list should be displayed as collapsed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: this does not contain any jquery, only javascript.

Comment: @kennypu. Done. jQuery tag removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added style="display:none" to the span element to make the list collapsed on default and no wrap in body in fiddle options.
http://jsfiddle.net/UDKLK/9/

```
<span id="objDetails" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1:**

Use `No-Wrap in body` in fiddle and get it working in fiddle :

[image]

**Solution #2:**

By default it's always collapsed! You can set `display:none;` to that if you don't want to get it callapsed.

*this is a pure javascript solution, there are many other solutions available, you may choose according to your need, if you are including any `jQuery` library in your website then i would recommend to use `jQuery`*

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UDKLK/12/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated your code a little = is should call toggle() function on document load:

```
toggle('objDetails')

function toggle(id){
var e=document.getElementById(id);
if (e.style.display == '') 
   {
       e.style.display = 'none'; 
   } 
else {
    e.style.display = '';
     }
}
```

Here's link: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UDKLK/6/)

Comment: and yes, as @DKM mentioned you gotta use `no-wrap in body` js option

Answer (score 0):

You needed to wrap the code in the head or body, not onLoad.

To make it collapsed by default just add:

```
#objDetails
{
    display: none;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UDKLK/5/)

Unrelated note: This contains no jQuery, just pure Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('objDetails').style.display = 'none';
```

You also have to add this line to javascript code.

Here is the **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UDKLK/10/)**